# How to shuffle a file[] using java collections?

Tags: java, list, collections

I am sure I missed something in my reading but I can't figure this out. My program gets a list of image files from a directory and then selects files at random to display as part of the game. The problem is, every time I have ran it using a random number generator it has duplicate numbers. In reading I saw Collections and I think that will work for me as it randomly shuffles the list. This eliminates the need for a random number generator. My problem is that I can not figure out how to get it to shuffle the File[].

This is the last thing I tried

```
comboFile =  filePath.listFiles();

    List listShuffle = new List();
    listShuffle = (List) Arrays.asList(comboFile);
```

Using list without  gets rid of that error but now the Collections.shuffle method is giving me an error. No suitable nethod found for shuffle(java.awt.list)

```
    Collections.shuffle(listShuffle);
```

How do I turn the File array into a list to shuffle?

Comment: please post the type of comboFile because if it is a java.awt.List that is a big part of your problem since this is not a Collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong type. Change your import to `java.util.List` instead of `java.awt.List`. The error is telling you there is no method that accepts the list type you're passing in.

And yes, you probably want to create the list using `Arrays.asList()` like the other guys suggested.

Answer (score 4):

The problem seems to be that `listShuffle` is never used after shuffling it. You are still reading the values from the `comboFile` array, which is never shuffled.

Also, it should be `Arrays.asList()` instead of `Array.asList()`.

Comment: I did not update the other code as I get an error message with array.asList(comboFile). The message is Cannot find symbol method asList(File[])

Comment: @user1793408: It is really hard for anyone to help if you do not include any errors. I updated my answer with what may be the solution to that problem.

Comment: Sorry about that I changed my code to focus specifically on the problem and listed the error message.

Comment: @user1793408: Did you try `Arrays.asList()` instead of `Array.asList()`, as suggested?

Comment: I have made the change as suggested, got some other errors that I worked through until I got stuck at the Collections.shuffle method.

Comment: @user1793408: Now you are creating a `java.awt.List` instance. What you actually want is a `java.util.List`, which is an interface. You cannot create an instance of an interface, which is why your IDE probably imported the AWT list implementation. Why do you create a list to overwrite it immediately? Try just `List listShuffle = Arrays.asList(comboFile);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please try Arrays.asList() function.

It will make a wrapper of the array. And call shuffle() function, which will change the inside array elements' order.